# Experiencing Performance Issues with framer-motion Animation in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, css-animations, framer-motion

I'm using framer-motion for animation in my React app, and I came across an example in the framer-motion documentation([link to the doc example](https://codesandbox.io/s/framer-motion-animate-on-state-update-ns67ib?from-embed)) that I decided to try out. However, after implementing it, I noticed that the final result is quite laggy.

here is the part of my code

```
import { useState } from "react"
import {motion} from "framer-motion"

const wrapperStyle = {display:"flex",flexDirection:"column", justifyContent:"center",alignItems:"center", height:"100vh"}
    const containerStyle = {width:"50vw", height:"50vh", display:"flex", justifyContent:"center", alignItems:"center", backgroundColor:"#E200D6"}
        const boxStyle = {backgroundColor:"white", borderRadius:"3px", height:"100px", width:"100px"}
const formWrapperStyle = {marginTop:"3em", color:"white"}
function BoxAnimation(){
    const [x, setX]  = useState(0)

    function xChangeHandler(event){
        setX(parseFloat(event.target.value));
        // console.log(x)
    }

    return(
        <div style={wrapperStyle}>
            {/* change it to simple div */}
            <div style={containerStyle}>
                <motion.div
                style={boxStyle}
                animate={{
                    x
                }}
                transition={{ type: "spring" }}
                />
            </div>

            <div style={formWrapperStyle}>
                <form>
                    <label htmlFor="x">x:</label>
                    <br/>

                    <input type="range" id="x" min={-100} max={100} value={x} onChange={xChangeHandler}></input>
                </form>                
            </div>
        </div>
    )
}
export default BoxAnimation
```

I would appreciate any guidance or suggestions to improve the performance of the animation.

Comment: I've added your code snippet into the de example sandobox, could you check if it's still laggy for you in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/framer-motion-animate-on-state-update-forked-4zkpd7?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark). On my machine it runs butter smoothly. there might be a different reason for the laggyness.

Comment: Yes i checked and it runs well on the sandbox environment, but when I run it on my laptop using 'npm start,' it doesn't perform well at all. Can you @Lars help me understand why this difference is happening?

Answer (score 0):

May be this code snippet work for you

for **npm** user

```
npm i use-debounce
```

for **yarn** user

```
yarn add use-debounce
```

import use-debounce in your BoxAnimation file

```
import {motion} from "framer-motion"
import { useDebounce } from "use-debounce";
```

Add this after you xValue useState

```
const [x, setX]  = useState(0)
const [debounceX] = useDebounce(x,150) /* 150 is miliseconds */
```

Last thing add debounceX to x value

```
<motion.div
    style={boxStyle}
    animate={{x:debounceX}}
    transition={{ type: "spring" }}
 />
```

**What is Debounce:**

Debouncing is a way of delaying the execution of a function until a certain amount of time has passed since the last time it was called.